# Get last numeric before certain word in PHP String

Tags: php, regex, string

I've php string that contain `pcs`, `Pcs`, or `PCS`.

#### How do I can get the last numeric before the word `psc`, `Pcs`, or `PCS`?

**Example:**

```
//string:
$fStr = '51672 : Cup 12 Pcs';
$sStr = '651267 : Spoon 128 pcs @xtra';
$tStr = '2 Pcs';

//expected result:
fStr = 12
sStr = 128
tStr = 2
```

**Is it possible using regex?**

Anyhelp will be appreciated. Thanks

### UPDATE:

The case above has been solved by the answer below. But how do I can handle if there's more than one word `pcs` inside the string.
**For example**

```
//string
$multiStr = '178139 : 4 Pcs pen and 2 Pcs book';

//expected result
Array
(
   [0] => 4
   [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: Use `(\d+)\s*pcs` with case insensitive flag and extract first captured group value.

Comment: @Tushar yah you're right. Just like the below answer that use regex and insensitive flag. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match()` to generate a fullstring match with a lookahead:

```
$sStr = '651267 : Spoon 128 pcs @xtra';
echo preg_match('/\d+(?= pcs)/i',$sStr,$out)?$out[0]:'';
```

Or `preg_match()` with a capture group and no lookahead:

```
$sStr = '651267 : Spoon 128 pcs @xtra';
echo preg_match('/(\d+) pcs/i',$sStr,$out)?$out[1]:[];
```

Or non-regex with string functions:

```
$sStr = '651267 : Spoon 128 pcs @xtra';
$trunc=stristr($sStr,' pcs',true);
echo substr($trunc,strrpos($trunc,' ')+1);
```

---

For multiple occurrences:

use `preg_match_all()` with a capture group:

```
$sStr = '178139 : 4 Pcs pen and 2 Pcs book';
var_export(preg_match_all('/(\d+) pcs/i',$sStr,$out)?$out[1]:'fail');  // capture group
```

or use `preg_match_all()` with a lookahead:

```
$sStr = '178139 : 4 Pcs pen and 2 Pcs book';
var_export(preg_match_all('/\d+(?= pcs)/i',$sStr,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

or non-regex with array functions:

```
$array=explode(' ',strtolower($sStr));
var_export(array_values(array_intersect_key(array_merge([''],$array),array_flip(array_keys($array,'pcs')))));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '4',
  1 => '2',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Actually I didn't upvote it, I don't know who has upvoted it, I just comment to tell there's a mistake there, It's got upvote after edited. Instead, I confused why I got downvote after get good respond from all of you.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou so much. The code for multiple also work so well. Yeah you maybe rigth about it, I'll take this as a learn. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(\d+)\ ?pcs/i', $string, $match);
$output = $match[1];
```

here's a [test](https://regex101.com/r/QUNvNy/1)

Answer (score 0):

=> Using `preg_match_all()` you can get all matched numeric value.

=> Then get last element from array using `end()`.

See example,

```
<?php
    //string
    $fStr = '51672 : Cup 12 Pcs';
    $sStr = '651267 : Spoon 128 pcs @xtra';
    $tStr = '2 Pcs 12 pcs 453 @xtra';

    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $tStr, $matches);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo end($matches[0]);
?>
```

See [Demo](https://eval.in/830598).

Comment: I think there's a little mistake in the code, but thanks for helping :)